# Does Ionic Pro Error Monitoring work with Ionic View?

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I just migrated my Ionic 2 app to Ionic Pro and followed the instructions in below link to setup error monitoring:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/monitoring/

But I couldn't figure out how it works so far, so here is my problem:

I am using HTTP module of @angular/http in my app for communicating with my API and I never needed proxies so far in legacy version since I was testing with chrome --disable-web-security feature and it used to work when I deployed to legacy Ionic View. However, after I deployed to Ionic Pro, I had to add proxy to use Ionic DevApp and when I deploy to Ionic View it doesn't work with proxy at all.

So I was expecting to see errors and logs when I test in Ionic View but the monitoring page in Ionic doesn't show anything.

Here is the part of the code in app.module.ts for error handling:

```
import { NgModule, Pipe, PipeTransform, ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Pro } from '@ionic/pro';

@Injectable()
export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    ionicErrorHandler: IonicErrorHandler;

    constructor(injector: Injector) {
        try {
            this.ionicErrorHandler = injector.get(IonicErrorHandler);
        } catch (e) {
            // Unable to get the IonicErrorHandler provider, ensure 
            // IonicErrorHandler has been added to the providers list below
        }
    }

    handleError(err: any): void {
        IonicPro.monitoring.handleNewError(err);
        // Remove this if you want to disable Ionic's auto exception handling
        // in development mode.
        this.ionicErrorHandler && this.ionicErrorHandler.handleError(err);
    }
}

  providers: [
      IonicErrorHandler,
      [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler }]
  ]
})
```

Also I tried manually sending errors inside my login.ts code:

```
import { Pro } from '@ionic/pro';

     err => {

          loader.dismissAll();
          var errorTitle = this.authService.connectionService.GetNoInternetConnectionErrorTitle();
          var errorMessage = this.authService.connectionService.GetNoInternetConnectionErrorMessage();
          if (err.status != 0) {
              console.log(JSON.parse(err._body));
              var errMessageJson = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(err._body));
              console.log("Error Code is " + errMessageJson.ErrorCode);
              errorTitle = errMessageJson.ErrorTitle;
              errorMessage = errMessageJson.ErrorMessage;
          }

          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: errorTitle,
              subTitle: errorMessage,
              buttons: ['OK']
          });

          // add error monitoring here
          Pro.getApp().monitoring.exception(new Error('Could not connect to API. Error Message is ' + errorMessage));
          Pro.getApp().monitoring.log('This happens sometimes Could not connect to API.  The whole message object is ' + err, { level: 'error' });

          alert.present();

      },
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears like the problem was I forgot to add api.ionicjs.com to connect-src in my Content-Security-Policy in index.html. I am able to see errors in monitoring page after adding this.

Comment: I have the same troubles, could you please post your Content-Security-Policy